# Jquery Table Pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i ve the following code for pagination of table using jquery

```
$('table.producttable').each(function() {
    var currentPage = 0,
        numPerPage = 3,
        $table = $(this);

    $table.bind('repaginate', function() {
        $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
    });

    $table.trigger('repaginate');

    var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length,
        numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage),
        $pager = $('<div class="pagination"></div>');

    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {

        $('<span class="page-number"></span>')
            .text(page + 1)
            .bind('click', { newPage: page}, function(event) {

                currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
                $table.trigger('repaginate');
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            })
            .appendTo($pager)
            .addClass('clickable');

    }
    $pager.insertAfter($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');
});
```

but the code doesnot output "next" and "previous" buttons..also paginates even if there is only one page...anyone who has a better code or can find solution to this plzz help